# Selecting variable column names for further IRR calculation in R

Tags: r, variables, select, dplyr, names

I have a table of cash flows for various projects over time (years) and want to calculate the IRR for each project. I can't seem to select the appropriate columns, which vary, for each project.  The table structure is as follows:

```
structure(list(`Portfolio Company` = c("Ventures II", "Pal III", 
"River Fund II", "Ventures III"), 
minc = c(2007, 2008, 2008, 2012), 
maxc = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2020), 
num_pers = c(14, 13, 13, 8), 
`2007` = c(-660000, NA, NA, NA), 
`2008` = c(-525000, -954219, -1427182.55, NA), 
`2009` = c(-351991.03, -626798, -1694353.41, NA), 
`2010` = c(-299717.06, -243248, -1193954, NA), 
`2011` = c(-239257.08, 465738, -288309, NA),
`2012` = c(-9057.31000000001, -369011, 128509.63, -480000), 
`2013` = c(-237233.9, -131111, 53718, -411734.58),
`2014` = c(-106181.76, -271181, 887640, -600000),
`2015` = c(-84760.51, 441808, 906289, -900000), 
`2016` = c(2770719.21, -377799, 166110, -150000),
`2017` = c(157820.08, -12147, 1425198, -255000),
`2018` = c(204424.36,-1626110, 361270, -180000),
`2019` = c(563463.62, 119577, 531555, 3300402.62),
`2020` = c(96247.29, 7057926, 2247027, 36111.6), 
`2021` = c(614848.68, 1277996, 258289, NA)), 
class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
groups = structure(list(`Portfolio Company` =c("Ventures II","Ventures III","Pal III", "River Fund II"),
.rows = structure(list(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L),
ptype = integer(0), 
class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Each project (`Portfolio Company`) has a different start and end date which is captured by the `minc` and `maxc` columns.  I would like to use the text in minc and maxc to select from minc:maxc for each project to perform the IRR calculation.  I get a variety of errors including: object `maxc` not found, incorrect arg ... Have tried about 20 combinations of !!sym, as.String (from NLP package) ... none works.

This is the code that created the table and the problematic select code:

```
sum_fund_CF <- funds %>% group_by(`TX_YR`, `Portfolio Company`) %>% 
  summarise(CF=sum(if_else(is.na(Proceeds),0,Proceeds)-if_else(is.na(Investment),0,Investment))) %>% ungroup() #organizes source data and calculates cash flows

sum_fund_CF <- sum_fund_CF %>%
  group_by(`Portfolio Company`) %>% mutate(minc=min(`TX_YR`),maxc=max(`TX_YR`),num_pers=maxc-minc) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TX_YR, values_from = `CF`) #creates the table and finds first year and last year of cash flow, and num of periods between them

sum_fund_CF %>% group_by(`Portfolio Company`)%>% select(!!sym(as.String(maxc))):!!sym(as.String(max))) #want to select appropriate columns for each record to do the IRR analysis ... IRR() ... need a string of cash flows and no NA.

I'm sure it's something simple, but this has me perplexed.  Thanks !
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Output should be a column of IRR values for each project.  Wanted to create a vector of cash flows from this table to feed into the IRR function.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your definition of IRR accordingly. I followed [this article](https://www.codingfinance.com/post/2018-03-20-irr/) on how to calculate IRR using the `jrvFinance` package.

The `filter` function from the `dplyr` package is used after `group_by`, to select the years indicated by the minc and maxc columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test
library(jrvFinance)

data <- structure(list(`Portfolio Company` = c("Ventures II", "Pal III", 
                                               "River Fund II", "Ventures III"), 
                       minc = c(2007, 2008, 2008, 2012), 
                       maxc = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2020), 
                       num_pers = c(14, 13, 13, 8), 
                       `2007` = c(-660000, NA, NA, NA), 
                       `2008` = c(-525000, -954219, -1427182.55, NA), 
                       `2009` = c(-351991.03, -626798, -1694353.41, NA), 
                       `2010` = c(-299717.06, -243248, -1193954, NA), 
                       `2011` = c(-239257.08, 465738, -288309, NA),
                       `2012` = c(-9057.31000000001, -369011, 128509.63, -480000), 
                       `2013` = c(-237233.9, -131111, 53718, -411734.58),
                       `2014` = c(-106181.76, -271181, 887640, -600000),
                       `2015` = c(-84760.51, 441808, 906289, -900000), 
                       `2016` = c(2770719.21, -377799, 166110, -150000),
                       `2017` = c(157820.08, -12147, 1425198, -255000),
                       `2018` = c(204424.36,-1626110, 361270, -180000),
                       `2019` = c(563463.62, 119577, 531555, 3300402.62),
                       `2020` = c(96247.29, 7057926, 2247027, 36111.6), 
                       `2021` = c(614848.68, 1277996, 258289, NA)), 
                  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                  row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                  groups = structure(list(`Portfolio Company` =c("Ventures II","Ventures III","Pal III", "River Fund II"),
                                          .rows = structure(list(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L),
                                                            ptype = integer(0), 
                                                            class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                                     row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))


clean_data <- data %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -1:-4,
               names_to = "year",
               values_to = "cashflow") %>%
  mutate(year = str_replace(year, "x", ""),
         year = as.numeric(year))


clean_data %>% 
  print(n = 20)
#> # A tibble: 60 x 6
#>    portfolio_company  minc  maxc num_pers  year cashflow
#>    <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2007 -660000 
#>  2 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2008 -525000 
#>  3 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2009 -351991.
#>  4 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2010 -299717.
#>  5 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2011 -239257.
#>  6 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2012   -9057.
#>  7 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2013 -237234.
#>  8 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2014 -106182.
#>  9 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2015  -84761.
#> 10 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2016 2770719.
#> 11 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2017  157820.
#> 12 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2018  204424.
#> 13 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2019  563464.
#> 14 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2020   96247.
#> 15 Ventures II        2007  2021       14  2021  614849.
#> 16 Pal III            2008  2021       13  2007      NA 
#> 17 Pal III            2008  2021       13  2008 -954219 
#> 18 Pal III            2008  2021       13  2009 -626798 
#> 19 Pal III            2008  2021       13  2010 -243248 
#> 20 Pal III            2008  2021       13  2011  465738 
#> # ... with 40 more rows

clean_data %>% 
  group_by(portfolio_company) %>% 
  filter(between(year, min(minc), max(maxc))) %>% 
  summarise(irr = irr(cashflow, 
                      cf.freq = 1))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   portfolio_company    irr
#>   <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1 Pal III           0.111 
#> 2 River Fund II     0.0510
#> 3 Ventures II       0.0729
#> 4 Ventures III      0.0251
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I had that table structure in place before I did the pivot_wider ... I went back to that point and added the minc and maxc columns and used the filter(between(year,min(minc),max(maxc) and the irr and worked !  Thank you.  This solved the specific problem of doing the IRR (which was the goal), but still wondering how to address columns whose names may vary as a function of the pivot.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, there are arguments in `pivot_longer` e.g. `names_to =` and `values_to =` that you can use to specify the column names after pivotting.

Comment: Yes ... but the names changes based upon the underlying data as they are `2007`, `2008` ... to `2021`.  The range of column names is a function of the years and the columns used in each calculation are different even though the table is created from the entire range ... hence i did the check on finding the minc and maxc which is equal to the numeric year ... was hoping to find a way to used minc and maxc to specifiy the columns to use.

Comment: I see. So you're saying you manually populated the `minc` and `maxc` columns. Instead, you could filter out the NA values using `filter(!is.na(cashflow))` and you'll have your range of values in the `year` column.

Comment: I populated them using the mutate command shown in the original code snippet I submitted.  Finding the minc and maxc was easy to do before the pivot wider because they were still numerics at that point.  Once the pivot is done they (and all the other years) become column names.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using `jvrFinance::irr()`.

```r
library(jrvFinance)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(irr = irr(na.omit(c_across(matches('^\\d')))), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   `Portfolio Company`    irr
#>   <chr>                <dbl>
#> 1 Ventures II         0.0729
#> 2 Pal III             0.111 
#> 3 River Fund II       0.0510
#> 4 Ventures III        0.0251
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>